# Two contents that overlap each other

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Let me try to explain scenario: I have a main view that looks like this (simplified):

```
<Grid>
  <ContentControl Content="{Binding RegularScreen}" /> <!--used for "regular" application views -->
  <ContentControl Content="{Binding DialogScreen}" /> <!-- used for dialog view -->
</Grid>
```

Regular screen is created first. While working on regular screen, a user triggers an action that requires a dialog screen to be shown to user. This dialog screen must cover completely the application, must not allow user to perform any other action but on this dialog. Dialog screen exists to:

- allow user to choose from given options
- when user selects an option, dialog screen closes, and this information is passed to regular screen.

To return to above code, when dialog screen is shown, DialogScreen is set to an instance of dialog screen. This is where the problem comes:

now we have both RegularScreen and DialogScreen contents shown (although the second one is visually overlapping the first one). Since in RegularScreen I have some InputBindings that monitor the keyboard, when I press some key while DialogScreen is shown, RegularScreen captures the key?!? This should never happen, and the only screen that should be handling the keys is DialogScreen (since it is on top of RegularScreen).

Any ideas why is this happening and any advice about what to change in design?

The reason why I have decided to have DialogScreen overlapping RegularScreen, is because RegualarScreen is quite complex screen, contains many tabs, and is very time/resource consuming to destroy it / recreate it every time a dialog screen is shown. This way I keep it "alive", and after I close the dialog screen, it shows immediately.

Comment: Is the DialogScreen a DialogWindow or just a control?

Comment: @lll Both RegularScreen and DialogScreen are UserControl.

Comment: Do you need to show the RegularScreen when DialogScreen is open?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is the natural effect of opening a dialog `Window` using [`window.ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog(v=vs.110).aspx). From the linked page:

> ShowDialog shows the window, disables all other windows in the application, and returns only when the window is closed. This type of window is known as a modal window.

So, as you can see, this automatically *disables all other windows in the application*. Perhaps you should try that instead?

Comment: Hi Sheridan, in the beginning DialogWindow was coded as Window, bit eventually since it was always Full screen, it was obvious that it would be much nicer (better looking) to be part of the app, instead as separate window). I would like to try solving the focus problem with the design as it is (no separate window for dialogs).

Comment: The problem is that we cannot provide a solution for you without being able to recreate your exact problem.